Why am I not finding .NET Framework 4.7.2 in my system from CMD?
I need .NET Framework 4.7.2 in my system.
When I check my Visual Studio 2017 environment, I see that I have .NET Framework 4.7.2 SDK installed in my OS environment.

However, when I query from the command line, I see the following:
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.5011]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\pc>reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" /v Version

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
    Version    REG_SZ    4.8.09037


C:\Users\pc>

DotNetVersions app also shows the same:

When I try to install .NET Framework SDK 4.7.2, the installer says that I cannot install it because I already have an advanced version installed.

Why am I not finding .NET Framework 4.7.2 in my system from CMD?

You cannot have 4.7.2 and 4.8 installed on the same machine. Since you already have 4.8, that should be sufficient. Whatever led you to believe you specifically needed 4.7.2 is either incorrect information or a badly built piece of software, but since you haven't shared where you got that idea from, it's difficult to correct.

.NET Framework 4.x versions are binary replacements (ie new ones replace old ones) and downgrading is impossible. All Windows 11 versions come with 4.8. You can check the .NET Framework versions installed by OS version here

Yes, 4.8 is a strict superset of 4.7.x, so if 4.8 is installed, any software that was built against 4.7.x will work OK.

I need .NET Framework 4.7.2 in my system. why? And why are you using such an ancient VS version? That's the real question. Are you maintaining some legacy SSIS or SSRS project that's tied to a specific SQL Server/Framework version? You can use newer versions to work on desktop or web apps and still target older SKDs (even though the target machine runs on newer runtimes). With SSIS/SSRS you can run into problems due to the VS designers, not the framework itself.

You should be rather asking this question.

You already have a newer version, you can just target 4.7.2 in your build, it will work fine.
